# Can you use Davmail to access Exchange archives?

Tags: email, sendmail, thunderbird

I have successfully set up Davmail on Ubuntu 14 and am able to read, receive and send mail on my Exchange account in Thunderbird. This page was a big help!:

http://nknu.net/ubuntu-14-04-exchange-configuration-thunderbird-pidgin/

I set the account up as IMAP, so I can also browse folders. One thing I can't seem to do is subscribe to or otherwise access the "Online Archive" - a copy of my Inbox and subfolders for all mail more than a year old (my IT department's policy). The posters in this thread claim success although the explanation of what options need to be changed lacks detail:

http://sourceforge.net/p/davmail/support-requests/134/

I'm pretty inexperienced with mailservers and these guys assume a lot of expertise. I need more specific instructions in how to change the settings of Davmail and my email clients. Can anyone help?

Cheers,
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got this working today. There are no special settings needed in DavMail, it's all done in your mail client. For example, in Thunderbird you can go to the Account Settings window, then navigate to the Server Settings pane for your account. Click the Advanced button and you will see a window like the following:

[image: Thunderbird Advanced Server Settings Window]

Notice the IMAP server directory is set to /archive, this is all that's needed to access the archive. I have not managed to access the root of the archive, only subfolders, but that's enough for my usage since I can move things from the root to a subfolder easily.

Hope that helps, if a little late.

Comment: If you leave "IMAP server directory" blank (the default) and put `/archive` in the "Public (shared)" field (as suggested [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/davmail/support-requests/134/#bf94), you will see the archive under a subfolder called "/archive". This has almost no disadvantages, because the rest of the account hierarchy looks the same as before, and there's no need to create a separate account _just_ to access your archive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible to leave Thunderbird's other IMAP server settings alone and just add `/archive` to the "Public (shared)" field within the IMAP server's "Advanced" settings (*Account Settings* → Account Name → *Server Settings* → "Advanced..." button).

You get access to your "Personal Archive" under a `/archive` subfolder within the sidebar hierarchy, and there's no need to sacrifice access to your "regular" Exchange mail or create a separate account in Thunderbird. So I haven't found any down sides (yet).

It *seems* to be necessary to **uncheck** the "Show only subscribed folders" checkbox as well; I didn't see any of my archive folders otherwise.

[image: Screenshot of IMAP "Advanced" dialog in Thunderbird 60]

It will probably be necessary to restart Thunderbird in order to see this new folder showing up in the sidebar (it was for me).

Be patient while it downloads and indexes, especially if you have a lot of history in your Exchange "Personal Archive" folders.

[Source](https://sourceforge.net/p/davmail/support-requests/134/#bf94)

Comment: I discovered this was apparently not possible anymore in 5.3.x using an EWS connection URL like `https://server.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`; with 5.2.x and an EWS (OWA) connection URL like `https://server.com/owa` this still works fine. So I downgraded.